# I'm having an error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: source is not async iterable

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ipfs

I'm using nft.storage for storing my data on ipfs using storeBlob as I want to store only data.

```
index.js:13 
        
       Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: source is not async iterable
    at last (index.js:13:1)
    at pack (index.js:14:1)
    at packCar (lib.js:757:1)
    at NFTStorage.encodeBlob (lib.js:472:1)
    at NFTStorage.storeBlob (lib.js:151:1)
    at NFTStorage.storeBlob (lib.js:542:1)
    at storeAsset (Results.jsx:36:1)
    at encryptingData (Results.jsx:63:1)
```

I used this function to get cid.

Here my metadata is encrypted string

```
const client = new NFTStorage({ token: NFT_STORAGE_KEY })
  async function storeAsset(metadata) {
    const cid = await client.storeBlob(metadata);
    console.log("Metadata stored on Filecoin and IPFS with cid:", cid)
 }
```

Comment: You should inspect the code of NFTStorage. The error is there somewhere. Not in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the below line?

Before:

```
const cid = await client.storeBlob(metadata);
```

After:

```
const cid = await client.storeBlob(new Blob([metadata]));
```

[blob Reference](https://nftstorage.github.io/nft.storage/client/modules/lib.html#Blob-1)

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: @DevyaniKalamkar Please share a jsfiddle or stackblitz with the minimum working example to debug

Answer (score 0):

client.storeBlob is probably expecting a stream. But, if all you really need is an async iterable you may be able to get away with this:

```
async function* makeAsyncIterable(metadata) {
  yield metadata;
}

const metadata = "???";
const metadataAsyncIterable = makeAsyncIterable(metadata);

console.log(Symbol.asyncIterator in metadataAsyncIterable); // Output: true
```

Comment: so what should I pass in storeBlob function

Comment: i passed metadataAsyncIterable to storeBlob function, still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what `metadata` variable is. this is how you should implement `client.storeBlob`

```
await client.storeBlob(
        new Blob([
          {
            chain:"goerli",
            contract_address: "0x....",
            transaction_hash: "0x....",
            description:"description",
            address:"0x.....",
          },
        ])
      );
```

Comment: my metadata is encrypted string

Comment: const cid= await client.storeBlob(new Blob([metadata]));      I tried this but i'm still getting the same error